# Rim Brake opening

Tags: brakes

I have rim brakes and when I want to take my wheels out I undo the release lever to allow more clearance for tire, but yet the tire still squeezes through the brake pads and then is very hard to put back on, So I tried loosening the brakes to see if this allowed more clearance but I ad to do it quite a bit and it meant when I broke, my lever was bottming out because it was now too loose.
Any ideas on how to solve this, any questions please ask.

Comment: Let the air out of the tire

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks very important information: what types of brakes you use. I suppose sidepull caliper brakes are most likely because other types (V brakes, cantilever brakes) usually don't have release levers -- however, some drop bar V brake levers may have a quick release at the lever.

A crude solution could be to use not only the release lever but also the barrel adjuster. Fully loosen the cable tension using the barrel adjuster (rotate it clockwise), and then use the release lever. If this doesn't help, then you may need to loosen the cable anchor bolt and re-set the location of the cable end in such a manner that you can barely remove the wheel with barrel adjuster fully loosened and release lever open.

However, the crude solution is not only slow (requires using the barrel adjuster every time you remove the wheel, and again after putting the wheel back in), but also requires some of the adjustment range in the barrel adjuster. It may mean that you are unable to wear the pads to the metal, because part of the range of the barrel adjuster is used to allow wheel removal and thus is unused for adjustment purposes as the pads wear.

A better solution would be to fit a Shimano SM-CB90 into the cable housing. This SM-CB90 has not only an additional quick release lever (releasing 4.5mm of cable), but also an additional barrel adjuster (having 13.5mm range). It works best with cantilevers and calipers, but with V brakes the quick release range may not be enough to allow you to unhook the noodle, and the 13.5mm adjustment range is not enough for these long-pull V-brakes to wear pads to the metal. So with V brakes you need more than one adjuster in the cable.

Install the SM-CB90 and you'll never have similar problems!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you undid the pinch bolt that holds the inner cable to the brake mech, and some wire has slipped past.  To fix that you need to reverse the process, by releasing the pinch bolt again and pulling some of the slack inner wire through.  There might even be a mark, a dent on the wire to show where it used to be secured.

As for getting fatter tyres through the brake calipers, there's only one workaround and that is to fit the wheel to the bike before inflating the tyre completely.  I forget to do this on my 28mm tyres, and have to let some air out even after releasing the brake's QR.